# $\epsilon$ undefined using Minion Pro with pdftex

Tags: fonts, minionpro

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and have recently installed the Minion Pro fonts for use with `pdftex`. I followed the instructions available on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) to install them.

Everything works as expected, but in place of the Greek letter epsilon I get a box with a cross (see below), and the following warning:

[image]

I found the issue was reported [here](http://meinews.niuz.biz/minionpro-t409793.html), but I still can't fix it. `xelatex` works fine, but I'd like to to stick to `pdftex` so I can use `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

Text here. $\epsilon$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** a set of instructions for the installation of the up-to-date FontPro scripts with MiKTeX can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87568/14497).

Comment: Which version of the `MinionPro` font do you have? (You can check with [`otfinfo`](http://www.lcdf.org/type/).) My (working) version is `Version 2.103;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.67;makeotf.lib2.5.29150`, which I got from (IIRC) `Adobe Reader 10` under MacOS X.

Comment: @ChristianClason My version is `2.103;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.67;makeotf.lib2.5.29150` (Adobe Reader 10 under Windows 7).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should update your encoding files. The scripts on CTAN are long out of date; the most up-to-date version (forked from the scripts on CTAN) can be found at https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/.

[image]

[This issue](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/issues/15) has also been raised for the new scripts, but could not be reproduced so far. Maybe some answer will emerge.

(Workaround: use `\varepsilon`.)

Comment: the use of `fontenc` makes no difference. (I've updated my MWE in any case.)

Comment: Then you should try reinstalling the font using the latest scripts I linked to; that is the version I (successfully) tested.

Comment: If you have a `bash` shell (e.g., from a `cygwin` installation) and the required tools, it should work under Windows. You should not change the `PATH` variable, but run the `makeall` script exactly as the instruction say: If you've unzipped everything into the folder (say) `FontPro`, you should create a subfolder `otf` under `FontPro` and then run from the `FontPro` folder (!) `./scripts/makeall MinionPro`.

Comment: Interesting and good to know that the scripts on CTAN are outdated. I think that should be mentioned there with a link to updated scripts.

Comment: @NunoNunes - If the package is already installed, you should not have to do anything (except possibly setting the path to include the corresponding directory). Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with MiKTeX and Windows. I think it would be a good idea to ask a new question on "Using FontPro with MiKTeX" (with a link to the new scripts); that way you have a much better chance of getting the experts to help you (who wouldn't necessarily see these comments).

Comment: @ChristianClason Understood. Many, many thanks once more for all your help. :- )

Comment: @NunoNunes - You are very welcome. Do ask that followup question; it would be very useful to have somewhere a set of instructions for using the new scripts on Windows.

Comment: @ChristianClason I contacted Sebastian Schubert about installing FontPro with MiKTeX, but he explained he hadn't tried it yet. I'll post a new question here on the SE later on today!