# installing FontPro (support for Minion Pro, Myriad Pro, & Cronos Pro) with MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: fonts, miktex, installing, minionpro

The Minion Pro distribution available on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) seems to be out of date. One issue with `pdftex` was reported on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87015/14497) (`$\epsilon$` is undefined using MinionPro).

The most up-to-date scripts (see [Christian Clason's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87017/14497)) can be found found at: https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/

I'm currently using MiKTeX 2.9, and would like to know if there is a set of instructions for installing the new scripts on Windows.

`xelatex` doesn't require FontPro obviously, but I wish to stick to `pdftex` so use can be made of `microtype`.

Comment: If the problem is only with the enc-files that you could change them manually (or try to use the one on github instead of the current one).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fonts can be installed via the bash shell from `cygwin`. Also you need to make sure that the right packages in cygwin are installed. A mininal setup and the `texlive-font-fontutils` (which contains the LCDF typetools) should suffice. (Alternatively the source source code of [LCDF Typetools](http://www.lcdf.org/type) may be used.) Then, for building the files you can follow the description on [github](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro). The binaries of the LCDF Typetools for Windows are not required with `cygwin`.

### Building

1) Put the sources in a FOLDER:

2) Copy your OpenType font files for MinionPro into the otf directory.

```
$ mkdir $FOLDER/otf
$ cp /some/path/*.otf otf
```

3) Run ./scripts/makeall for Minion.

```
$ ./scripts/makeall MinionPro
```

Now repeat steps 1-3 with a new folder, but replace MinionPro with MyriadPro. Alternatively you can use the same folder, but then you have install the font first and run `$ ./scripts/clean` before starting with Myriad.

### Installing

Installing is only a bit different from the description on github.

1. Run `./scripts/install /cydrive/c/path/to/Miktex` in the cygwin bash. Note that `c/path/to/Miktex` has to be replaced with path to the local Miktex installation, but cygdrive is the folder where the windows drives can be accessed. (A local texmf tree can be created in MiKTeX for this purpose. Instructions found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/14497). Then we may run something like `./scripts/install /cydrive/c/localtexmf` in the Cygwin bash.)
2. In the windows prompt run `initexmf -u`
3. In the windows prompt use the command  `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap`. Then add 
   `Map MinionPro.map`
   `Map MyriadPro.map`
   and save.
4. In the windows prompt run  `initexmf --mkmaps`

Now everything should work and you should be able to use the fonts via `\usepackage{MinionPro}` or `\usepackage{MyriadPro}`.

---

Comment: Thanks for writing this. How did you install the LCDF typetools? As Windows binaries or in cygwin?
It might also not be a good idea to create MinionPro _and_ MyriadPro support files with the same folder. I'll check the ``clean`` command over holidays.

Comment: @sebschub with maetra's permission, I'll edit his answer (or add a longer comment) and explain what I did. I'm almost done with the building part.

Comment: @NunoNunes I've edited the answer, you have to replace the path with your Miktex-path, but cygwin uses a different place for it than Windows. /cygdrive/c is equal to C: in windows. You can use `tab` to make it easier to find the location.

Comment: @NunoNunes feel free to edit the answer where it needs improvements. I did that some time ago, so maybe I forgot to mention something.

Comment: @sebschub would you then advise creating the support files for MinionPro and install them first, then repeat the process for MyriadPro?

Comment: @NunoNunes I think I used separate folders but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: @sebschub [texlive-collection-fontutils](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=texlive-collection-fontutils%2Ftexlive-collection-fontutils-20120312-2-src&grep=lcdf) contains the LCDF typetools, so I used them.

Comment: @sebschub many thanks for maintaining these packages. I really like to use them.

Comment: @maetra I added your guide to the README and linked to your answer. I hope this ok.

Comment: @sebschub That's just fine with me.

Comment: @NunoNunes, I integrated the comments directly in the answer, which imho is easier to read