# MinionPro and Cyrillic

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, minionpro

In my style file I have

```
\usepackage[OT2, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
```

And then I use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The Conception of Complementarity: An Historical and Methodological Analysis \emph{[in Russian]} = \foreignlanguage{russian}{\emph{Alekseev I. S.} Kon{ts}ep{ts}i{ya} dopolnitel{p1}nosti: istoriko-metodologi{ch}eski\u{i} analiz}
\end{document}
```

If I use the MinionPro font then the end result is just a load of boxes. But when I use the default (by removing the \usepackage{MinionPro} font then I get the desired result, as seen in this picture:

[image]

The error message I get when using MinonPro is something of the following form:

> pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file
>   C:/Users/Mats/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts
>   /type1/Adobe/MinionPro/MinionPro-It.pfb): glyph `afii10022' undefined

So what am I doing wrong?
(Running MiKTeX 2.9)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There's no font for the OT2 encoding in the MinionPro family, I'd say.

Comment: @egreg, according to the Documentation of MinionPro there is an OT2 encoding, but may be it has not been installed, for FontPro there is a feature --cyrillic

Comment: If that is indeed the case, then how to I install the OT2 encoding?

Comment: First, make sure that there are no files named OT2MinionPro*.fd in ...\MikTeX\tex\latex\MinionPro. If that is the case, then take a look at the [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) site, but first uninstall your current version to avoid conflicts. (btw, use @name to notify other commentators)

Comment: Still working on the FontPro install (from the directions posted here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87557/installing-fontpro-support-for-minion-pro-myriad-pro-cronos-pro-with-mikte)

But I figured out one possible (temporary) solution for my problem: I switch the font from MinionPro to the default one at those portions when I need Cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short description of what I did. I am not sure what exactly did the trick, but at least I got my stuff to work.

I followed the instructions found here: http://kobi.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/patrick/pmwiki.php?n=Wiki.HOWTO-InstallMinionProInLATEXOnWindows

And then I did the same thing again, except for Local and not Roaming folder in AppData.

Then I deleted the updmap.cfg file found in the Roaming folder and then it worked.