# MinionPro on Windows 7 does not have \epsilon

Tags: fonts, symbols, miktex, minionpro

I have installed MinionPro fonts under Windows 7 using Miktex 2.9 by following the steps in the instruction you can read online on Scribd ([mpro_installation_miktex_windows_machine.pdf](http://www.scribd.com/doc/98777195/mpro-installation-miktex-windows-machine-pdf)) and load down for free from LaTeX Community ([Installation Guide for Minion Pro and Myriad Pro on MiKTeX](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=8415)).

Everything works well except that `\epsilon` is substituted by a rectangle. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathlf,textlf,minionint]{MinionPro}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}
\begin{document}
$\epsilon$
\end{document}
```

I have seen some solutions suggested here but they require installing `cygwin`, running different shells and makefile, etc., that for a Windows guy are overwhelming. I was wondering if there exist an easier solution that does not require these steps.

Comment: Does `$\alpha$` work? And wouldn't `$\varepsilon$` work? Some fonts don't have two glyphs for epsilon. I would test it, but I really don't have W7.

Comment: I added a free download link. On Scribd I am forced to subscribe for a payed account, when I want to download the document, though it is declared free.

Comment: Oh, I see I may be wrong in my older comment: I am forced to subscribe, but there seems to be a free account. More important: In this document one link is dead, it slightly changed. The file `MyriadProAR7.zip` can be downloaded from http://faq.ktug.org/wiki/uploads/MyriadProAR7.zip

Comment: @tohecs: \alpha and \varepsilon both work.

Comment: The problem is probably that you use a too recent font version not supported by the original MinionPro package.[FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) indeed solves this but needs you to use cygwin etc as you said. As a reward, the resulting MyriadPro packages fully supports math!

Comment: @sebschub: I am open to go through cygwin, etc. steps. Is there a step by step clear guide (for newb non linux/unix oriented) guys similar to (mpro_installation_miktex_windows_machine.pdf) to do this?

Comment: @per Please have a look at [this guide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87557/installing-fontpro-support-for-minion-pro-myriad-pro-cronos-pro-with-mikte/87568#87568). Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on how you see it `;)`), I don't use Windows and cannot give more detailed advice.

Comment: @sebschub Oh, seems that this question here is actually a duplicate of another one linked in the question you refer to.